# sweetalert2 TypeError: this is undefined after v8 upgrade

Tags: sweetalert2

I moved from `sweetalert2  ^7.32.4  →  ^8.11.7`, I read the [v8.0.0 breaking changes](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2019-01-19) and none of [my code](https://gitlab.com/rawsec/rawsec-cybersecurity-list/blob/master/js/sweetalert2.js) directly call one of the impacted functions.

I wonder what is causing this mysterious error: (`TypeError: this is undefined`)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to see the new documentation examples, and they are all launching the popup with `Swal.fire()` when before `Swal()` alone was valid.

The problem is that if you check [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for `fire` you don't see any mentions of that function. But this is a breaking change as it was earlier not mandatory and now is.

[Here](https://gitlab.com/rawsec/rawsec-cybersecurity-list/merge_requests/104/diffs#396c28c01101edbebeccdcafd2ee865d1f87ac67) is the fix for my specific problem.

Answer (score 5):

As reported in the SweetAlert2 [release note for version 8.0.0](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v8.0.0) referenced at the top of the README, this major version release introduced a breaking change in the way the `Swal` is invoked. In the release note there is also a link to the reason why this breaking change has been introduced.

The changelog is actually including this breaking change under the title ["BREAKING CHANGE: remove withNoNewKeyword enhancer"](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/commit/f581352). The content of this commit explains:

> From now on the recommended way to use SweetAlert2 is:
>   Swal.fire({...options})

Comment: As you said it is in the content of the commit, not in the Changelog, one will not review every commit to understand the changes, else a Changelog would be useless.
But thanks for pointing the it is written the the release tag https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v8.0.0 but not in the https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md